# I am trying to make a search programm but don`t know how to print the username with the fullname

Tags: python

```
import datetime

tday = datetime.date.today()
username =input('input something:')


class person:
    def __init__(self, first, last, ip, birtyear, birthmonth, birthday):
        self.first = first
        self.last = last
        self.ip = ip
        self.birthyear = birtyear
        self.birthmonth = birthmonth
        self.birthday = birthday
    def fullname(self):
        return '{} {}'.format(self.first, self.last)
    def yearage(self):
          return '{}'.format(tday.year - self.birthyear)
    def monthage(self):
          return '{}'.format(tday.month - self.birthmonth)
    def dayage(self):
          return '{}'.format(tday.day - self.birthday)
    def birth(self):
        b1 = self.birthmonth, self.birthday,
        b2 = self.birthyear
        return'{} {}'.format(b1, b2)
    def ip1(self):
        return'{}'.format(self.ip)


names = ['x1', 'x2']

x1 = person('x1', 'y1', 50000, 2002, 2, 22)
x2 = person('x2', 'y2', 60000, 2004, 4, 24)

flag = 0
for i in names:
    if (i==username):
        print ((username).fullname())
        flag=1
        break

if (flag == 0):
    print("element not found")
```

Comment: Try `print(f'{username} - {fullname()}')` See [Formatted string literals](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#whatsnew36-pep498).

Answer (score 1):

You need to add your persons to a list so you can search through it.  Just because you have a variable called `x1` does not mean you can use `(username).fullname()` to refer to that variable.  Python doesn't work that way.

```
names = [
    person('x1', 'y1', 50000, 2002, 2, 22)
    person('x2', 'y2', 60000, 2004, 4, 24)
]

flag = 0
for user in names:
    if user.first == username:
        print( user.first, user.fullname())
        flag=1
        break

if flag == 0:
    print("element not found")
```

Comment: Is it also possible if there are more then 1 'x1' to count them?

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking. You should post a new question with your current code.

Answer (score 0):

The `username` is just the string the user gave as an input.
It therefore doesn't have the function `fullname()` you implemented for the `person` class.

I don't know what you are aiming for, you can either print the hardcoded `"x1 y2"` in the end or just reply what the user typed in.